# Preventing gaming of Tag only edits

Tags: discussion

When doing some reviews I often find myself skipping tag only edits if the user even looks a little suspicious of being a possible edits gamer, and it's made me curious about how I should go about either accepting or rejecting these tag only edits?

EDIT:
[Preventing gaming of Tag only edits](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2141/preventing-gaming-of-tag-only-edits?noredirect=1#comment5630_2141)
So someone asked for some clarification, so here goes:
User with some generic name, no profile picture, no other SE accounts asks a question with some popularity. Eventually it will fall off of the front pages.

Within a small window of that happening, an edit comes along that is a tag only edit by someone with an established presence on SE and edits only the tag.

I'm curious how I should handle these cases and if I should bother to try and prevent points gaming with edits and tag edits, or if the gain would be so small as to just accept the edit.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I often edit tags only on a question, especially if it relates to one of the areas where I often answer (e.g. usability / desktop / linux).

I feel it's normal to do this and is good hygiene for the website over time. How is it a problem?

Comment: @SteveDL made an edit that should help clarify it, also tried to link to your comment for reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not tag gaming as far as I can tell. This is a perfectly normal activity, usually carried out by long-standing members of the community as they have an understanding of what tags may be needed.

This is cleaning up and improving.

When reviewing, please just check that the tag edit is appropriate and approve if so.